# Can you put a Sphere of Annihilation into a Bag of Holding without tearing a hole in reality?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, magic-items

As long as you can fit a Sphere of Annihilation into a Bag of Holding without touching it (and costing you your Bag), could you put the Sphere into the extradimensional space of a Bag of Holding and carry it around as your mobile disposing device/magic murder bag/orphan pickpocket deterrent/whatever? Or is this not possible?

Comment: +1 for "orphan pickpocket deterrent" and for giving me something I never knew I needed.

Comment: https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/96313/can-a-bag-of-holding-destroy-a-sphere-of-annihilation/96315 related, provides a better reading of the SoA

Answer (score 15, accepted):

## A *bag of holding* can hold a *sphere of annihilation*...

- if the DM rules the extradimensional space accessed by a *[bag of holding](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/magicItems/wondrousItems.htm#bagofHolding)* is fixed (i.e. once an item's in the *bag* the item doesn't move when the *bag*'s moved), and...
- if the [*sphere of annihilation*](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/magicItems/artifacts.htm#sphereofAnnihilation)'s 2-ft. diameter can be manipulated to such a size as to fit in the *bag* (or the opening of the 2-ft.-×-4-ft. *bag* can be increased), and...
- if the *sphere* can be navigated into the bag *via* the necessary control check.

The first part's easily determined--toss an item into the *bag*, look in *bag*, note item's location in the *bag*, close *bag*, shake *bag*, look in *bag* again; if the item's moved, *don't try to put the sphere in the* bag!

The second part might require a custom-made *bag of holding*. The third part's just a d20 + the attempted controller's level + his Intelligence modifier *versus* DC 30 each round until it's in the *bag*. Good luck with that.

Please, when you try this at the gaming table, either get a summoned monster to do the control checks or stay the maximum distance away you can from the *sphere*. Chances are the DM won't tell you what'll happen before you try this kind of stuff.

Comment: Please, when you try this at the gaming table, tell us what happens!

Comment: @WesleyObenshain I have tested this with 3 DMs.  The results: **DM 1**: (on step #1, where you look in the bag) "No." (me) "What happens?  Is the rock still there?" (him) "Just no.  We're not doing this.  Moving on." **DM 2**: (on the last step, and also every other step except step one, which he rolled for) "Does that work?" (me) "Uh, I think so.  I'm not sure though, that's part of why I'm trying this." (him)"Oh.  Uh... [discussion of reasons to allow and disallow it]"  (him again) "Yah, ok, you can do that." **DM3**: (step 1 again) The item moved.

Answer (score 6):

I have tested this with 3 DMs.  In each case I acquired a bag of holding type IV and stuck a rock in.  In the case of DM#2, the only case which got past that point, I also hunted down a sphere of annihilation and one of those talisman things. The results:

**DM 1:** (on step #1, where you look in the bag) "No." (me) "What happens? Is the rock still there?" (him) "Just no. We're not doing this. Moving on."

**DM 2:** (on the last step, and also every other step except step one, which he rolled for) "Does that work?" (me) "Uh, I think so. I'm not sure though, that's part of why I'm trying this." (him)"Oh. Uh... [discussion of reasons to allow and disallow it]" (him again) "Yah, ok, you can do that."

**DM3:** (step 1 again) The item moved.

Comment: DM 1 has clearly been around the block a time or two with you.

Comment: forget "nip it in the bud"; he's seen these kinds of things before. break the branches, uproot the plant, burn it, salt the earth, and in egregious cases further methods may still be required.