# Can a Bag of Holding destroy a Sphere of Annihilation?

Tags: dnd-5e, magic-items

So looking at the description of a [Sphere of Annihilation](https://www.dndbeyond.com/magic-items/sphere-of-annihilation), it says:

> If the sphere comes into contact with a **planar portal**, such as that created by the [*gate*](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/gate) spell, or an **extradimensional space**, such as that within a [*portable hole*](https://www.dndbeyond.com/magic-items/portable-hole), the DM determines randomly what happens [...]

(Emphasis mine).

Now I have seen debates about what a [Bag of Holding](https://www.dndbeyond.com/magic-items/bag-of-holding) actually is, but I'd like to know if there's a RAW answer about what happens if you put a SOA in the Bag of Holding, specifically will it potentially destroy it? More specifically:

**Is the Bag of Holding considered an extradimensional space for the purposes of the random effects of the sphere?**

Answer (score 34, accepted):

### Yes, a Bag of Holding could potentially destroy the Sphere

If we look at page 225 of [the 5e SRD](http://media.wizards.com/2016/downloads/DND/SRD-OGL_V5.1.pdf), under the magic item *Handy Haversack*, we see the following:

> Placing the haversack inside an **extradimensional space created by a *bag of holding*, *portable hole*, or similar item** instantly destroys both items [...]

(emphasis mine)

From this, we can determine that the inside of the *Bag of Holding* indeed contains "an extradimensional space, such as that within a portable hole." The logic being that if the space in the bag is close enough to that of a *Portable Hole* to destroy the Haversack, it is similar enough for the *Sphere of Annihilation*. So, if the sphere is placed into the *Bag of Holding*, a random result is determined by the DM, which can include the destruction of the sphere.